# Convert an array of numbers to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an array of numbers to array of objects. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
myArray = [1,2,3];

myObject = convertToObjects(myArray);

convertToObjects= (items) => {
    let listOfItems = [];
    let convertToObj = items.map(item, idx => {
      let key = item;
      listOfItems.push({ key });
    });
    return listOfItems;
  }
```

Thank you!

Expected output:

```
[
{key: 1},
{key: 2},
{key: 3}]
```

Comment: [MDN map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `myArray.map(x => ({key:x}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the object.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3],
    convertToObjects = items => items.map(key => ({ key })),
    myObject = convertToObjects(myArray);

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` function has as parameter a `callback` function.

> `map` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
>   array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

Read more about [map method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Try this:

```js
myArray = [1,2,3];

myObject = convertToObjects(myArray);

function convertToObjects(items){
    let listOfItems = [];
    let convertToObj = items.map(function(item) {
      let key = item;
      listOfItems.push({ key });
    });
    return listOfItems;
  }
console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

@qxz provided an answer in the comments

> `myArray.map(x => ({key:x}))`

Here is a brief explanation.

`map()` is a function of Arrays. It calls a provided callback function for each element, then returns an Array of the results. [See the documentation for `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

`map()` returns an array, rather than modifying it in place, so you'll need to capture the result.

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3],
var convertedArr = myArray.map( function(item) {
    return {"key": item};
});

console.log(convertedArr);
```